# Show all items with empty attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with several list items, which are all hidden:

```
<ul>
    <li rel="">
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I want to show list items where attribute `rel` is just an empty string.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with CSS and an attribute selector:

```
ul li[rel=""] {
    display: list-item;
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$('ul li[rel=""]').show();
```

Use a `data-` attribute or figure out a way to not use attributes in the first place.

Comment: `rel` is valid in `a`, `area` and `link` elements, according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Comment: Did you see my comment? maybe worth to edit/remove that on the answer. Cheers

Comment: @Sergio: Yep, I changed it to "not on `<li>` elements".

Comment: I meant the text "rel attribute isn't valid on <li> elements". Anyway, +1, its a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using like this

```
$('ul li').hide();
$('ul li[rel=""]').show();
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kPLTR/)**

Answer (score 0):

In jquery

```
 $("li[rel!='']").show();
```